# Need advice on how to proceed with Yesod install

Tags: yesod

I interpret the following error to mean that a Yesod dependency, authenticate-0.10.2.2, requires attoparsec ==0.9.*, but Yesod itself requires attoparsec >=0.10. What can I do to resolve this?>

> ```
> Resolving dependencies...
> cabal: cannot configure authenticate-0.10.2.2. It requires attoparsec ==0.9.*
> For the dependency on attoparsec ==0.9.* there are these packages:
> attoparsec-0.9.0.0, attoparsec-0.9.1.1 and attoparsec-0.9.1.2. However none of
> them are available.
> attoparsec-0.9.0.0 was excluded because attoparsec-enumerator-0.3 requires
> attoparsec ==0.10.*
> attoparsec-0.9.0.0 was excluded because yesod-0.9.4.1 requires attoparsec >=0.10
>
> attoparsec-0.9.1.1 was excluded because attoparsec-enumerator-0.3 requires 
> attoparsec ==0.10.*
> attoparsec-0.9.1.1 was excluded because yesod-0.9.4.1 requires attoparsec
>
>  >=0.10
>   attoparsec-0.9.1.2 was excluded because attoparsec-enumerator-0.3 requires
>   attoparsec ==0.10.*
>   attoparsec-0.9.1.2 was excluded because yesod-0.9.4.1 requires attoparsec
>  >=0.10
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why cabal is trying to installing an older version of authenticate. Try putting a lower bounds on it, i.e. `authenticate >= 0.10.4`, that should work.